# Fill a percentage of an SVG and animate the fill

Tags: html, css, svg

Currently, I am working on a project that is comparing state data with data from another country. One data point is percentage of protected land and I want to fill the a percentage of the state that matches the data point. So for example, if 25% of North Carolina is protected, then I want 25% of the state to fill. Currently, I am trying to use an svg and I want the fill to happen on page load.

Any suggestions or resources on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Example I drew up in Illustrator:

[image: NC filled in 33%]

Comment: This is not a site where you ask people to write code for you

Comment: @CodyGuldner I am not looking for the code. I have been scouring the internet for some way to successfully animate the fill to a percentage of the state and cannot. I just need someone to point me in the right direction. No code need be written.

Comment: I almost always see color-coding of state data rather than partial-fills.  I would find partial-fills difficult to quickly understand.  Just saying....

Comment: When you say _"25% of the state to fill"_ what do you mean? A bar graph sliding through the state from left to right? Do you want it to be 25% of the width of the bounding box? 25% of the fill area? Do you just want the fill color to be 25% opaque? -1 for lack of information; edit your question with more details and I will remove the downvote and also help answer.

Comment: @markE You make a valid point, and is something I will discuss with my partner on this project, but I would like to try and make it work as I think it is a simple, graphical way to demonstrate what percentage of the state is protected land.

Comment: @Phrogz I need to fill the inside area if the state. Like markE said, this is normally done by filling in the whole state and having some comparison to other states, but that tactic doesn't satisfy the message I am trying to convey. Therefore, I am looking for a way to fill a percentage of the inner area of a state, almost as if it is a progress bar. It gets complicated because of the odd shapes of the shapes, as you know.

Comment: @hi_Matt This is getting close to enough detail. Now, is 33% based on just left-to-right distance of the bounding box? Or percentage of total area?

Comment: @Phrogz That's a good question, something I had not considered. I'd like to use total area, as I feel that would be more accurate. Therefore, 33% of the total area will be filled because 33% of NC land is protected. Thank you for your patience, Phrogz

Answer (score 6):

Here are my two cents:

You can have a linear gradient like this:

```
<linearGradient y2="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" x1="0%" id="F1g"><stop stop-color="#00FF00" offset="0%" id="F1gst1"/><stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%" id="F1gst2"/></linearGradient>
```

Then take the first stop element:

```
var firstStop = document.getElementById('F1gst1');
```

And then assign the percentage you want fill, with the attribute offset:

```
percentage = '35%'; firstStop.setAttribute('offset',percentage);
```

And that is the way in javascript. You need a gradient for every state (you can use a group) and maybe you will need to define a path object with a fill inside every state with the same form, so you can apply the linear gradient to that path fill attribute.

If you need an animation, you can set a setInterval, and add an '1%' every x miliseconds to make the effect, and stop every interval when the desired percentage is reached.

I hope this at least have given you a clue.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by plain css and html: http://jsfiddle.net/haohcraft/rAPN5/1/

Basically, the trick is

1. You need a image which has a transparent inner field but
   non-transparent outer field, like the image in the fiddle. And you
   need to set `z-index:1` in order to place it above the `filled
   <div>`.
2. Set the `filled <div>` and the `img` to be `position: absolute; width:90px; height:90px;` in that case.
3. Then you can adjust the `height` of the `filled div` to show the *percentage*

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a pretty dumb way in Canvas...(and I'm assuming you mean you want a certain % of interior area filled).

Step 1: Dump a solid image of each state into Canvas

Step 2: Count the number of nonzero pixels

Step 3: Extract the edges using an edge extraction convolution

Step 4: For each line, iterate horizontally within each row within the shape, coloring in pixels until you've reached the x% of the shape you'd like to portray.

It is possible to do this in SVG, but you'd need to hand-tesselate the shape, track all your areas and then hand calculate the ones to fill and it wouldn't do what I think you want - which is to have a state fill up like it's a water container?

An alternative solution is, of course, to 3D print transparent containers in the shape of all 50 states, fill them with colored water to the desired levels. Photograph them, and then manipulate that image via an SVG filter (feImage + feColorMatrix+feComposite) to selectively fill an SVG image. This may be faster than learning tesselation (or Canvas).

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar looks promising and easy to use:
https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

Here's a nice Fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/72tkyn40/

Javascript:

```
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
  color: '#aaa',
  // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
  // prevent clipping
  strokeWidth: 4,
  trailWidth: 1,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  text: {
    autoStyleContainer: false
  },
  from: { color: '#aaa', width: 1 },
  to: { color: '#333', width: 4 },
  // Set default step function for all animate calls
  step: function(state, circle) {
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
    circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
      circle.setText('');
    } else {
      circle.setText(value);
    }

  }
});
bar.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
bar.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```