# fill imagebased on number / percentage with color in js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, image

I am searching a possibility to fill a image based on percentage.

Is there a dynamic way to do that or is it easier to create images in a specific interval?

I'm using angular and need to set the percentage of a 1 to 5 rating system from AJAX.

[image: rating_star]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this answer: [Fill a percentage of an SVG and animate the fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885980/fill-a-percentage-of-an-svg-and-animate-the-fill)

What you can do is create an SVG [form of a star](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html):

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <polygon fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" 
            points="350,75  379,161 469,161 397,215
                    423,301 350,250 277,301 303,215
                    231,161 321,161" />
</svg>
```

And then apply linear gradient to it with smth like:

```
<linearGradient y2="100%" x2="100%" y1="100%" x1="0%" id="F1g">
  <stop stop-color="#00FF00" offset="0%" id="F1gst1"/>
  <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%" id="F1gst2"/>
</linearGradient>
```

By any means this way is faster to implement and more flexible and less network-intense than creating and showing several gradual images.

Comment: I found that too; I asked just to make if there is a way in combination with javascript.

Comment: that post already contains some js

Answer (score 1):

Just using two images and a little of javascript, I'm pretty sure you could do this easily. Just have one image that is transparent where you want it to be filled. Then position an image of the same dimension, just filled with the filling color, just behind the first image (use the `z-index` css property for that), at the bottom of it. With your javascript, move it up to "fill" the first image. Here is a link to a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bw2wqaq/) demonstrating the principle

It is definitely not as clean as a solution with an SVG, but at least you can use it with pretty much any image.